# Arbitrary name for RESTEasy QueryParam?

Tags: java, get, resteasy, query-string

Is there a way to get any query parameter without explicitly declaring its name using the @QueryParam annotation?

I have a string which may have tokens like {animal}, which are then replaced by the query parameter posted, e.g. ?animal=fox, but I want the name of the token to be configurable as well. Ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
for (QueryParam param : queryParams) {
    text = text.replaceAll("{" + param.key + "}", param.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm guessing you are talking about writing a resource to accept a query string correct?)

In which case, in your method, you can use [@Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) to get a [UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) object which you an use to obtain a [MultivaluedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) of all of your query string parameters.